# find the closest pair values from another data frame under a group condition in r

Tags: r

I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 = read.table(text="group    value
    A   24163
    A   80991
    A   81014
    A   81352
    A   81353
    A   81367
    A   81368
    B   71721
    B   76038
    B   113186
    B   126732
    B   126748
    B   155556", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

    df2 = read.table(text="group    value
    A   30000
    A   40000
    A   81360
    B   75000
    B   90000
    B   130000", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I want to find the closest pair of values for each of `df2$value` from `df1$value` under the same group. one is the closest value in `df1$value` less than the value in `df2$value`, another on is the closest value in df1$value more than the value in `df2$value` under the same group. So the expected result:

```
    df = read.table(text="group value   low high
    A   30000   24163   80991
    A   40000   24163   80991
    A   81360   81353   81367
    B   75000   71721   76038
    B   90000   76038   113186
    B   130000  126748  155556", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would like to find a solution without looping.

Answer (score 0):

Merging `df2` with `df1` by `group` gives all possible combinations -

```
x = merge(df2, df1, all.x = TRUE, by = "group")
```

Then, the matches can be characterized by difference and direction (higher or lower) -

```
x$diff = x$value.x - x$value.y
x$type = ifelse(x$diff < 0, "high", "low")
```

Ordering by *absolute* difference and removing duplicates per "direction" keeps just the closest "high" and "low" -

```
x = x[order(x$group, abs(x$diff)), ]
x = x[!duplicated(x[, c("group", "value.x", "type")]), ]
```

The table with the results looks like this -

```
##     group value.x value.y   diff type
##  19     A   81360   81353      7  low
##  20     A   81360   81367     -7 high
##  1      A   30000   24163   5837  low
##  8      A   40000   24163  15837  low
##  9      A   40000   80991 -40991 high
##  2      A   30000   80991 -50991 high
##  23     B   75000   76038  -1038 high
##  38     B  130000  126748   3252  low
##  22     B   75000   71721   3279  low
##  29     B   90000   76038  13962  low
##  30     B   90000  113186 -23186 high
##  39     B  130000  155556 -25556 high
```

Some reshaping and renaming are left to be done to match the format in your expected result `df` -

```
library(reshape2)
x = dcast(x, group + value.x ~ type, value.var = "value.y")
names(x) = gsub(".x", "", names(x))
x = x[, c("group", "value", "low", "high")]
all.equal(x, df)
## [1] TRUE
```